# Why does sshtunnel prevent SIGINT from closing my python app?

Tags: python, ssh

If you take this short bit of code:

```
import sshtunnel

# The IP of any system with an SSH server on port 22
ip = "localhost"

print "Connecting to ssh..."
with sshtunnel.open_tunnel(ip, ssh_username="test",
                           ssh_password="test",
                           remote_bind_address=("1.2.3.4", 23)) as server:

    print "SSH connected"

print "SSH Closed"
```

Set the "ip" variable to any system that is running an SSH server on port 22, run the code, and try to interrupt it with Ctrl+C just after it prints "Connecting to ssh...", it will give you a traceback and freeze (not exit).
What's holding it up?

Comment: If I use PyCharm to run the above code, and pause it after a KeyboardInterrupt (when it's frozen waiting for something), it seems to stop on this line in packet.py: `x = self.__socket.recv(n)`. packet.py appears to be a paramiko module. Does this meant anything to anyone? Is this something the sshtunnel library, or paramiko should have handled better? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Seems related to this: https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/520. Will investigate when I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed at the moment `sshtunnel` is not considering any signals.
You can workaround by running:

```
server = sshtunnel.open_tunnel(ip, ssh_username="test",
                               ssh_password="test",
                               remote_bind_address=("1.2.3.4", 23))
try:
    with server:
        print "SSH connected"
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "Pressed Ctrl-C"
    server._stop_transport()

print "SSH Closed"
```